# Circumventing the null check while populating a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

While inserting into a hashmap, do I always have to check if there is a null value  corresponding to the key being inserted?

For instance, if I want to keep track of the number of times a character occurs in a word, using a hashmap, do i always have to do:

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(ch)){
    hashMap.replace(ch, 1+hashMap.get(ch));    
}
else{
    hashMap.put(ch, 1);    
}
```

Or is there a function that can handle this for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

```
hashMap.merge(ch, 1, (left, right) -> left + right);
```

or using a method reference:

```
 hashMap.merge(ch, 1, Math::addExact);
```

- If the specified key (`ch` in this case) is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value (`1` in this case).
- if the specified key is associated with a non-null value it then replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function `(left, right) -> left + right`.

Comment: This is a bit late, but isn't `hashMap.put(ch, hashMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0)+1); ` also a valid option?

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to. `Map` has a `merge` method which you can use to update a value:

```
hashMap.merge(ch, 1, (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal + newVal);
```

What that does:

- If `hashMap` doesn't already have a `ch` key, then a new entry is added with `ch` as key and `1` as value
- If `hashMap` already has an entry with `ch` as key, then the last function is called to compute the update value. In this case, `(oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal + newVal` simply adds the old value to the new one.

As pointed out in [Andy's comment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), you can also use `Map.compute`:

```
int newValue = hashMap.compute(ch, 
      (key, existingVal) -> (existingVal == null) ? 1 : existingVal + 1);
```

Comment: You can also use `compute` (I think merge is implemented using that).

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you do not have to distinguish between whether the key exists in the map already or not. In other words, instead of using `replace` in your example, you could use `put`.

Of course, you do need to deal with whether or not you have a prior value that you need to include in the updated value. As others have noted, you can use the `merge` or `compute` methods.

However, if you have reasons to prefer to stick with `put` here are a couple of ideas for how to structure the code.

In your original code,

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(ch)){
    hashMap.replace(ch, 1+hashMap.get(ch));    
}
else{
    hashMap.put(ch, 1);    
}
```

you call `containsKey` and `get`, both of which essentially do a lookup. Why do the lookup twice?

```
Integer count = hashMap.get(ch);
if(count != null){
    hashMap.replace(ch, 1+count);    
}
else{
    hashMap.put(ch, 1);    
}
```

Instead of using `replace` for one case and `put` for the other, you can just as easily use `put` for both. And you can combine the cases:

```
Integer count = hashMap.get(ch);
if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}
hashMap.put(ch, count + 1);
```

I find this pattern to be very useful and it comes up a lot (at least in the applications that I work on). Here is the way I think about this:

```
// Get the current value.
Integer count = hashMap.get(ch);
if (count == null) {
    // Business logic for initial value.
    count = 0;
}

// Compute the new value (might be a bunch of business logic).
count++;

// Put the new value back.
hashMap.put(ch, count);
```